# Does stackoverflow have apis that can be used to create plug ins on other web sites?

Tags: api, plugins

I would like to know if stackoverflow has api's that can be used as plug-ins to be put on other websites ?

Lets say in another forum , a guy posts a question , is it possible to use any api and transfer the question to stackoverflow and then transfer the answers back to the forum ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an API, but it can't be used as you describe.  The API is read-only in its current version (1.0), so you can't create or edit posts yet.  See StackApps [API Documentation and Help](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help) for information on what capabilities the API gives you.